# angularJS and regex on value output

Tags: regex, angularjs

I've been handed a JS regex function that is run on a form to correctly brand products on a page.

I'm rebuilding the page using angularJS and need to similarly apply that regex as each product name is output but I'm unsure how best to do this...

so I am writing out the products in my ng-repeat simply as {{product.name}} but how can I apply this branding ruleset to this output...

The following regex checks for branding pattern and applies a html style as needed:

```
var regex = /(Brand1|Brand2) ([-\w\s+]+)([â„¢Â®])/
val = val.replace(regex, "$1 <strong>$2$3</strong>");
```

It may help if I post the full JS as it does a sense check first to see if TM or (R) is in the product name in which case the branding check/regex should be used.

```
if (val.indexOf('™') !== -1 || val.indexOf('®') !== -1) {

            // Check for exceptions
            if (val.indexOf('Special BRAND 1') !== -1 || val.indexOf('Special BRAND 2') !== -1) {

                val = val.replace("Special BRAND 1™", "Special BRAND <strong>1&trade;</strong>");
                val = val.replace("Special Brand 2™", "Special Brand <strong>2&trade;</strong>");

            } else {

                /*  The products not an exception so run regex
                */

                var regex = /(Brand1|Brand2) ([-\w\s+]+)([™®])/

                val = val.replace(regex, "$1 <strong>$2$3</strong>");

            }

        }
```

Comment: Sorry - so the question is how do I apply that branding rule to the angular value I am writing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) can be a good solution.

```
angular.module('yourModule').filter('brandRegex', function() {
    return function(val) {
        //do whatever you want to do and return the changed value
    };
});
```

In your HTML:

```
{{product.name | brandRegex}}
```

Comment: That is a thing of beauty thanks! That being said I am getting a branded output however any text wrapped in a strong tag is writing the literal strong in angular brackets out...

Comment: that can also be solved, but it's a little more complicated since you want to inject html tags into your html code. you can achieve this with `ng-bind-html`, which requires you to include `angular-sanitize` as a resource. here's a simple example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Kv96xIdwW22KNMuXfQan?p=preview